# Access the call history from Windows phone 7

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

I'm new to Windows phone7 development. Can i know whether there is permission to access the call history from Windows phone7 using Windows phone SDK?

And what programming languages are preferred for developing applications in Windows phone7?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 7 call history - Mango API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882990/windows-phone-7-call-history-mango-api)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to access the call history (privacy).
You can only select a contact to get his number with [PhoneNumberChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.phonenumberchoosertask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

> Allows an application to launch the Contacts application. Use this to obtain the phone number of a contact selected by the user.

Languages to develop applications for Windows Phone are C # and VB.NET. You can find examples on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: Can you look at [Phone API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416387.aspx) and tell me what is it doing? Can i use this API to access the call history from Windows phone 7?

Comment: No, its not possible (privacy reasons )

Answer (score 0):

Refer 
 [Windows Phone 7 call history - Mango API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882990/windows-phone-7-call-history-mango-api)

You can use C# or VB.net for backend coding and xaml for ui.