# How to find call log(history) information in windows phone 'mango'?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, calllog

I am unable to find call log in windows phone 'mango'.

When I was searching for this i found below link-
[Windows Phone 7 call history - Mango API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882990/windows-phone-7-call-history-mango-api)

Is there any other way to find call log in windows phone 'mango'?

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 7 call history - Mango API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882990/windows-phone-7-call-history-mango-api)

Answer (score 0):

As that link suggests correctly, that is impossible to do with today's APIs.